# Servicem8 API - Staff Jobs are scheduled to

Tags: json, web-services, rest, servicem8

We are building an integration between Servicem8 and Unleashed and I'm trying to find out if we can get the staff member the job is scheduled to via the Servicem8 API.

If not, is there another way for us to identify the staff member?

Comment: I might be missing something but browsing the Servicem8 web site I do not see any C++ APIs. Why is this question tagged C++?

Comment: No you aren't missing anything. I am not a developer but work with developers and I am updating our scoping document for the client. Servicem8 told us to come on here if we had API questions and this forum forced me to add a tag. I just added the first one which was C++

Comment: You should not tag a question that is not appropriate. I retagged it with some more appropriate tags. Also please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Well @harmic I think that it isn't appropriate for ServiceM8 to send me to this site when clearly it isn't for non developers - Sorry I bothered you.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine if a job is scheduled by querying the jobActivity endpoint. Records with `activity_was_scheduled` == 1 are scheduled bookings (records with `activity_was_scheduled` == 0 are check-ins recorded for the job).

JobActivity records have a `staff_uuid` property which tells you the Staff member assigned to that scheduled booking.

```
GET https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/JobActivity.json?%24filter=job_uuid%20eq%20'your_job_uuid_here'
```

Note that you can have multiple scheduled bookings per job, each assigned to different staff.

Comment: Thank you @telomere. It sounds like it will be safer for use to use a custom field.